# Setting a custom projection in ArcGIS, from data provided by the Government of Mauritius?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, datum, mauritius

I am trying to save a custom projection in ArcGIS. It is a local projection used by the Land Unit from the Government of Mauritius. Below are the information provided by the government:
[image]

My question is, what is the Latitude of Origin in the "New Projected Coordinate System" console in ArcGIS (shown below). Is it the latitude of the "Origin: Verdun PTo0391" ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Latitude of Origin of LGM2012 is the the "Central Latitude" that they mention, which is 20°16'31.85868"S (-20.2755163 in decimal degrees). We can easily verify that this actually corresponds to the origin (PTP0391) when looking at the coordinates of the Mauritius Control Network:

[image]

Which are indeed the same as the Central Latitude and Longitude mentioned.

The terms *Central Latitude/Parallel* and *Latitude of Origin* are both used to define the origin of the y-coordinates, however in some projections, like Lambert Conformal Conic, a *Latitude of Origin* could be located outside the standard parallels, meaning it may not always be located at the center of the projection.

For the Geographic Coordinate System, make sure it uses the WGS84 ellipsoid, as this is the reference ellipsoid of the Mauritius Datum (GDM 2008). I'm not sure ArcGIS has GDM 2008 as a GCS, but you could always create it too, using WGS84 as the ellipsoid.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. To add on to my initial question, does the Central Meridian remain 0.0 and the Scale Factor 1.0?

Comment: Your Central Meridian is the Central Longitude, E57° 33' 52.40384" (57.564556622). Also, make sure to choose the correct projection on top under "name": it's Lambert Conformal Conic, not Transverse Mercator. You will then get the option to enter your standard parallels (mentioned as Parallel 1 and 2 in your document)